# How to populate dataset legends in Chart.js?

Tags: json, dataset, legend, chart.js

I'm using a bar chart with CHART.JS

First, an image so you can see the problem:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DOkE.jpg

I want to populate the legends with the labels of the charts, in other words, instead of "UNDEFINED" legend, I want a legend for each label ("error", "lost", etc).

Here's the code:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'WebService1.asmx/GetDatabyStage',
                data: "{stage:['All']}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: onSuccess,
                error: OnErrorCall
            });
            function onSuccess(response) {
                console.log(response);

                var dataset = {
                    data: []
                };
                var labels = [];
                data=response;


                data.d.forEach(function(d) {
                    dataset.data.push(d.col2);
                    labels.push(d.col1);

                });

                var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'horizontalBar',
                    animation: true,
                    data: {
                        datasets : [dataset],
                        labels: labels
                    },

                    options:{

                        }
                }); 
            };
```

Any help would be so appreciated, thanks.